# Dataframe : Convert python list to group of dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a list

data_list

```
    [['mark', 1], ['tom', 2], ['mark', 3], ['mark', 4], ['tom', 5], ['stuart', 6]]
```

Passing data_list values to function here.

```
    for name_list in data_list:
        convertMerge(name_list)
```

And a function which takes list and converts it to df and save it.

```
    def convertMerge(name_list):
        df = pd.DataFrame([name_list],columns=['name','id'])
        df.to_csv('names'.csv)
```

I'm trying to merge/append/concat the df's if it has same `name`.

(This must happen inside the `convertMerge` function ).

Resultant output should have df like this:

```
     df with mark 

            mark.csv

                name    id
            0   mark    1
            1   mark    3
            2   mark    4

    df with tom 
          
            tom.csv

                name    id
            0   tom     2
            1   tom     5


    df with stuart

            stuart.csv`

                name    id
            0   stuart  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
>>> master_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns = ['name', 'ID'])
>>> for key, sub_df in master_df.groupby('name'):
        sub_df.reset_index(drop=True).to_csv(key + '.csv')
```

For your function:

```
def convertMerge(name_list):
    df = pd.DataFrame(name_list,columns=['name','id'])
    for key, sub_df in df.groupby('name'):
        sub_df.reset_index(drop=True).to_csv(key + '.csv')

convertMerge(data_list)
```

If printed it looks like this:

```
>>> master_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns = ['name', 'ID'])
>>> for key, sub_df in master_df.groupby('name', sort=False):
        print(key + '.csv')
        sub_df.reset_index(drop=True)

# output:
mark.csv
   name  ID
0  mark   1
1  mark   3
2  mark   4
tom.csv
  name  ID
0  tom   2
1  tom   5
stuart.csv
     name  ID
0  stuart   6
```

Comment: Thanks. But i need the logic inside the `convertMerge` function

Comment: @luknajirku added, check

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(name_list,columns=['name','id'])` should be `pd.DataFrame([name_list],columns=['name','id'])`.

And df formed contains only last values from the list. Not appened as per sample ouput in question

Comment: Not adding `index= False` while saving will generate an extra index column. Edited the code to fix it.

Comment: @RishabhVij please check OP's intended output. OP wants the indices.

Comment: @luknajirku I don't understand. If `name_list` is a list of list, it should not be `[name_list]`. And as you see in the printed output, it is exactly what you posted as your expected output.

Comment: @SayandipDutta Without [name_list] i'm getting this `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 1), indices imply (2, 2)
`

Comment: Ah, I see. You are calling it on each sub_list. you do not need that now. Remove the `for` loop at the end of the code. And simply call `convertMerge(data_list)`. @luknajirku please see the edit below the function in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solution also works, using [unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
data_list = [['mark', 1], ['tom', 2], ['mark', 3], ['mark', 4], ['tom', 5], ['stuart', 6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=['name', 'id'])
for name in df['name'].unique():
    df.loc[df['name'] == name].to_csv(name + '.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks. But i need the logic inside the `convertMerge` function

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) :

```
pd.DataFrame([['mark', 1], ['tom', 2], ['mark', 3], ['mark', 4], ['tom', 5], ['stuart', 6]], columns = ['name', 'ID']).groupby('name').apply(lambda d: d.to_csv(f'{d.name}.csv', index=False))
```

Comment: Thanks. But i need the logic inside the `convertMerge` function

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want to:

```
data_list = [['mark', 1], ['tom', 2], ['mark', 3], ['mark', 4], ['tom', 5], ['stuart', 6]]
def convertMerge():
  df = pd.DataFrame()
  for name_list in data_list:
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([name_list],columns=['name','id']))
    [y.reset_index(drop = True).to_csv(x + '.csv', index = False) for x, y in df.groupby('name')]
convertMerge()
```

Comment: Thanks. But the order must be the same the question. `For loop` should be outside the function

Comment: That will not be a very efficient way to achieve what you want. If you want the for loop to be outside, then you don't need the function at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution that you like ... logic is in ***`convertMerge`***

```
data_list = [['mark', 1], ['tom', 2], ['mark', 3], ['mark', 4], ['tom', 5], ['stuart', 6]]

def convertMerge(name_list):
    name = name_list[0]
    df = pd.DataFrame([name_list],columns=['name','id'])
    
    if not os.path.isfile(f'{name}.csv'):
        df.to_csv(f'{name}.csv')
    else:
        df.to_csv(f'{name}.csv', mode='a', header=False)
        
for name_list in data_list:
    convertMerge(name_list)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can data be appended/merged before converting to csv?

Comment: You can do it outside the **convertMerge** function